# Objective-C++ ARC and C++ containers

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, clang, libc++

I'm trying to compile my legacy-free libFoundation project, located at https://github.com/chmeeedalf/lf-foundation but running into problems using clang 3.4 and libc++.  It appears something is not happy with ARC in the containers, and I see the following error excerpt:

```
In file included from /home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src/Collections/NSCoreArray.mm:34:
In file included from /home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src/../Headers/Foundation/NSArray.h:31:
In file included from /home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src/../Headers/Foundation/NSObject.h:40:
In file included from /home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src/../Headers/Foundation/NSRange.h:192:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:913:17: error: call to 'addressof' is ambiguous
        {return _VSTD::addressof(__r);}
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:341:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_NAMESPACE
              ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1678:65: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::pointer_traits<const __strong id *>::pointer_to' requested here
            const_pointer __xr = pointer_traits<const_pointer>::pointer_to(__x);
                                                                ^
/home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src/Collections/NSCoreArray.mm:115:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<id, std::__1::allocator<id> >::insert' requested here
        items.insert(items.begin() + index, anObject);
              ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:96:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = const id]
addressof(__strong _Tp& __x) _NOEXCEPT
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:122:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = const id]
addressof(__unsafe_unretained _Tp& __x) _NOEXCEPT
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:83:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = const id]
addressof(_Tp& __x) _NOEXCEPT
^
1 error generated.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /home/chmeee/git-lffoundation/src
Exit 1
```

The file in this example has a `std::vector` declared as:

```
    std::vector<id> items;
```

Can someone shed some light onto this problem?  I tried adding an explicit `__strong` in the `std::vector` declaration, to no avail, however `__unsafe_unretained` does eliminate the error.

I'm building on FreeBSD -CURRENT, using the libc++ and clang 3.4 that is in base.

Comment: Does `std::vector<__strong id> items` or `std::vector<__unsafe_unretained id> items` work?

Comment: `std::vector<id> items;` works for me. Xcode 5.0.2 with clang version: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Comment: @GregParker: No, it doesn't.  I tried `std::vector<__strong id> items` and got the same result.

Comment: @BryanChen: Thanks for trying it.  I'm guessing now that it may be a bug in clang and/or libc++.

Comment: That's likely. STL containers are expected to just work with ARC. It's possible that std::vector<id> works for most things but that you found some operation that needs a fix.

Comment: @GregParker, I deleted my incorrect answer to avoid future confusion, but can you explain how the ObjC++ restriction on "nontrivially ownership-qualified types are considered non-POD" applies (or doesn't) to STL collections? I would think that this would cause problems with std::vector<id> moving in and out of ARC. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions

Comment: Moving in and out of ARC *is* a problem for C++ STL containers. The ARC version is not compatible with the non-ARC version unless you use __unsafe_unretained.

Comment: @GregParker: What is required for the C++ STL containers to be ARC-compatible?  I just tested with __unsafe_unretained, and that does "work" (I don't get the error message, but I highly doubt the container is safe this way).  Would this point to a bug in clang/libc++?

Comment: My guess is that it's a flaw in libc++ somewhere in the templates that your code is using. But I'm not an expert here, especially with the state of the world outside OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in case others are interested.  `Clang` defines `__weak` as a preprocessor macro for ARC.  However, FreeBSD's `<sys/cdefs.h>` also defines `__weak` itself.  The workaround I found for this was to add to my local `<sys/cdefs.h>`:

```
#ifndef __weak
#define __weak what_freebsd_defines_ass
#endif
```